# Modelling piecewise function in GLPK

Tags: linear-programming, glpk, mathprog

I am trying to use GLPK to solve an optimization problem for which I have a piecewise function (2 sub-functions).
In short, the problem is about minimizing energy costs in an environment by scheduling the operation of certain (electrical) appliances. Production of energy is also being considered, rendering my objective function to be the minimization of the following function:

[image: objective function]

The idea is that, for each instant, **balance[i]** will store the overall energy balance (that is, the difference between energy consumed and produced). Therefore, if balance[i]>= 0 the amount of energy demanded surpasses production and we need to buy energy from the grid; otherwise, production exceeds demands and we can sell excess energy to the grid.

For each time instant, the value of **balance[i]** will depend on energy production, fixed energy consumptions (both previously known, so no problem variables involved) and on energy consumptions of scheduled appliances (computed as a function of the problem variables).

In trying to model this in GLPK I introduced a binary variable that, for each instant i, tells the signal of **balance[i]**. The idea is to write the objective function as:

> minimize obj: sum {i in k} (z[i]*balance[i]*buy + (1-z[i])*balance[i]*sell)

Thus, I want z[i] to be 1 when balance[i]>= 0 and z[i] to be 0 otherwise (balance[i] < 0).

How can I define the constraints on z[i]? I know one can define conditional constraints in GLPK, but as far as I know I can't write:

> s.t. zUpperi{i in k: balance[i] >= 0}: z[i] = 1;

because balance[i] depends on problem variables... Are there other ways of expressing this constraint? Or is this not even possible in GLPK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach

```
minimize obj: sum {i in k} (z[i]*balance[i]*buy + (1-z[i])*balance[i]*sell)
```

makes the problem nonlinear (quadratic) as you multiply two variables. In general we can do:

```
minimize obj: sum {i in k} (posbal[i]*buy + negbal[i]*(-sell)) 

# constraints 
posbal[i] - negbal[i] = balance[i]
posbal[i] <= z[i]*maxbal[i]
negbal[i] <= (1-z[i])*maxbal[i]

# bounds
posbal[i] >= 0, negbal[i] >= 0
-maxbal[i] <= balance[i] <= maxbal[i]
z[i] binary
```

where `maxbal[i]` is a constant bound on `balance[i]`. I assume `sell,buy` are constants.

Often this construct can be simplified further, but that depends on the details of the model.

Comment: No, your conclusion is wrong. In no shape or form did I get rid of the variable `balance`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! Yes, `buy` and `sell` are both constants.
If I understood your suggestion, this removes the computation of `balance[i]`, correct? We replace the product `z[i]*balance[i]` by `posbal[i]` (and the same for `negbal[i]`)
The problem for me is that, while `balance[i]` is computed based on problem variables, I still need to used the values assigned to them in other constraints, and by imposing upper bounds on `posbal[i]`I don't think I can make it have coherent values with the other variables. Maybe this can't be done in LP... Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: My mistake, you're right. `posbal` and `negbal` have the desired values. This solves my problem! Thank you again